# R Error: there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, package

My output says "Package 'ggplot2' successfully installed." but when I try to run library(ggplot2) I get the error "there is no package called ‘ggplot2’"

I have already updated R and uninstalled/reinstalled the package with no luck.

Comment: Check `.libPaths()`. Is `ggplot2` installed in one of those directories?

Comment: You say the output says *"successfully installed"* ... is it in the same R session (no restart) where you try `library(ggplot2)` and it fails?